# Getting the element in foreach.click function in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            $("label img").each(function (i) {
              $(this).click(imageClikced);  
            });
        }
    });

   function imageClikced(img) {
        alert(img.type);
    }
```

in alert box I am getting img.type as click. How should I pass the image to the imageClikced function as parameter.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but inside the `imageClicked` function, `this` will be a reference to the clicked element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context object of an event handler (`this`) is the element it self so do this

```
function imageClikced() {
   alert(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to a jQuery event handler is the [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), which has a property `type` that tells the type of the event that was fired.

You can refer to the image from [`.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) of the event object:

```
function imageClikced(e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget);
}
```